# Get unique combination (combn) by ID in R

Tags: r, data.table, combn

I try to get unique combination by each ID, I keep get error, it doesn't expand ID.

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
var1 <- c("A","B","E","F","C","D","C","A","B","C","A","D","B","C",
      "A","B","C","A","D","C","A","B","C","E","F","G")
df1 <- data.frame(ID,var1)
df1 <- df1[order(df1$ID, df1$var1),]
dd <- unique(df1)
dd <- data.table(dd)
dd[,new4 := t(combn(sort(var1), m = 3))[,1],by= "ID"]
dd[,new5:= t(combn(sort(var1), m = 3))[,2],by="ID"]
dd[,new6:= t(combn(sort(var1), m = 3))[,3],by="ID"]

Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dd, , `:=`(new4, t(combn(sort(var1), m = 3))[,  :
RHS 1 is length 10 (greater than the size (5) of group 1). The last 5 element(s) will be discarded.

     ID var1 new4 new5 new6
 1:  1    A    A    B    C
 2:  1    B    A    B    E
 3:  1    C    A    B    F
 4:  1    E    A    C    E
 5:  1    F    A    C    F
 6:  2    A    A    B    C
 7:  2    B    A    B    D
 8:  2    C    A    C    D
 9:  2    D    B    C    D
10:  3    A    A    B    C
11:  3    B    A    B    D
12:  3    C    A    C    D
13:  3    D    B    C    D
14:  4    A    A    B    C
15:  4    B    A    B    C
16:  4    C    A    B    C
17:  5    A    A    B    C
18:  5    B    A    B    D
19:  5    C    A    C    D
20:  5    D    B    C    D
21:  6    C    C    E    F
22:  6    E    C    E    G
23:  6    F    C    F    G
24:  6    G    E    F    G
```

The output doesn't give enough combination by each ID, ID1 (A,B,C,E,F), it gives only 5 combinations. There is anyway fixing the problem?Output I want for ID1, there are 10 combinations (A B C) (A C F) (A B F) (A B E) (B C E) (B C F) (C A B) (C A E) (C A F) (E C F)

Comment: You are assigning it to the dataset where the original number of rows is less than the new `combn` length.

Comment: @akrun : Is there some way to counter that?

Comment: how we expand the same length of data before using cobm

Comment: @BIN You seem to want the `var1' column with the same length as the combinations.  But I am not sure how the elements in 'var1' would be replicated.  Please show your expected output

Comment: @akrun dd[rep(1:.N,each = 3)][,new4:= t(combn(unique(var1), m = 3))[,1], by = .(ID)], I found this way, it fixed the length, but then I got so many combination, the only one I need unique combination like (ABC) or (ADE) not (AAB)

Comment: @akrun just update

Comment: @BIN This should give the correct combinations `dd[,  transpose(combn(sort(as.character(var1)), 3, FUN = list)), by = ID]` but if we want to have the 'var1' also in the output, I am not sure how you wanted

Comment: @akrun I guess `simplify=FALSE` is a more standard way to achieve that than `FUN = list`.

Comment: @akrun, still give me error, I may find different way how to get combination

Comment: If it's giving you an error, maybe you need to use `data.table::transpose` and have some other package with a namespace conflict causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

@BIN Since the number of combinations will not usually match the number of unique letters for "Var1", you can try the following:

```
 library(dplyr)      
 dd[,var1:=as.character(var1)]

 dd[,.(Numb.Combinations = choose(var1 %>% uniqueN,3),
             ID1 = paste0(var1 %>% unique, collapse=""),
      Combinations = paste(combn(var1,3,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = "")),collapse="-")),   
   by="ID"]
```

The output is similar to the one that you requested at the very end:

```
   ID Numb.Combinations   ID1                            Combinations
1:  1                10 ABCEF ABC-ABE-ABF-ACE-ACF-AEF-BCE-BCF-BEF-CEF
2:  2                 4  ABCD                         ABC-ABD-ACD-BCD
3:  3                 4  ABCD                         ABC-ABD-ACD-BCD
4:  4                 1   ABC                                     ABC
5:  5                 4  ABCD                         ABC-ABD-ACD-BCD
6:  6                 4  CEFG                         CEF-CEG-CFG-EFG
```

Or if you prefer, as suggested by @akrun and @frank,

```
 dd <- dd[, c(ID1 = paste0(var1 %>% unique, collapse=""),
             transpose(combn(sort(var1), 3, simplify = F))), by = ID]
colnames(dd) <- c("ID","ID1","New1","New2","New3")
```

With output:

```
    ID   ID1 New1 New2 New3
 1:  1 ABCEF    A    B    C
 2:  1 ABCEF    A    B    E
 3:  1 ABCEF    A    B    F
 4:  1 ABCEF    A    C    E
 5:  1 ABCEF    A    C    F
 6:  1 ABCEF    A    E    F
 7:  1 ABCEF    B    C    E
 8:  1 ABCEF    B    C    F
 9:  1 ABCEF    B    E    F
10:  1 ABCEF    C    E    F
11:  2  ABCD    A    B    C
12:  2  ABCD    A    B    D
13:  2  ABCD    A    C    D
14:  2  ABCD    B    C    D
15:  3  ABCD    A    B    C
16:  3  ABCD    A    B    D
17:  3  ABCD    A    C    D
18:  3  ABCD    B    C    D
19:  4   ABC    A    B    C
20:  5  ABCD    A    B    C
21:  5  ABCD    A    B    D
22:  5  ABCD    A    C    D
23:  5  ABCD    B    C    D
24:  6  CEFG    C    E    F
25:  6  CEFG    C    E    G
26:  6  CEFG    C    F    G
27:  6  CEFG    E    F    G
    ID   ID1 New1 New2 New3
```